# how to Add timeout for WKWebview

Tags: ios, wkwebview

How to write a timeout handler for `WKWebView`, when default delegates are not getting called for `didFailNavigation`.

`WKWebView` delegate are set & `DidFinishNavigation` or `didFailProvisionalNavigation` is getting called.

Answer (score 18):

Use the **error.code** value of the error that **didFailProvisionalNavigation** creates and add your 'handler' code there:

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {

        if error.code == -1001 { // TIMED OUT:

            // CODE to handle TIMEOUT

        } else if error.code == -1003 { // SERVER CANNOT BE FOUND

            // CODE to handle SERVER not found

        } else if error.code == -1100 { // URL NOT FOUND ON SERVER

            // CODE to handle URL not found

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this delegate method

```
 webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError:
```

Document

> Invoked when an error occurs while starting to load data for the main frame.

And check the error code

```
NSURLErrorTimedOut = -1001
```

All the error [code list](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes)

Comment: Even that delegate is not getting called.

Comment: Heads up: it took more than a minute for that delegate method to be called when I requested an invalid URL and received a NSURLErrorTimedOut

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add custom timer, which starts as you call `loadHTML`, `loadRequest` methods and times out on custom interval

Answer (score 0):

Compared to `Timer` , `asyncAfter(deadline:)` is more light-weighted.

```
var isTimeOut = true

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeOut) {
      if isTimeOut{
            // do time out thing
      }
     
}
```

check `isTimeOut` according to `WKNavigationDelegate`

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!){

      isTimeOut = false
}
```